# Split sentence into separate words and the full-stop if at the end of sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, text, tokenize

I need to tokenize and process a string that is based on a programming language.

For example, lets use the following string:

```
"      THE QUICK BROWN FOX    JUMPED-OVER THE LAZY(2) DOG."
```

In javascript I can do the following to split it up into an array:

```
var v = "      THE QUICK BROWN FOX   JUMPED-OVER THE LAZY(2) DOG.".match(/\S+/g);
```

This results in the following array:

```
["THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPED-OVER", "THE", "LAZY(2)", "DOG."]
```

How can I change the regular expression on the match to make the fullstop a separate element, thus producing an output of:

```
["THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPED-OVER", "THE", "LAZY(2)", "DOG", "."]
```

Please Note:

- I cannot use \w as it splits out the 2 into a separate token, dropping the parentheses and removes the fullstop.
- This is not a duplicate question, as other questions on splitting sentences do not deal with the issue of the fullstop while adequately handling parentheses.
- If this is not possible via a regular expression then is it possible to remove the fullstop from the last token, such that the last token becomes "DOG"?

Comment: Aren't '(', '2' and ')' separate tokens?

Comment: @RobG If I were tokenizing, I'd tokenize everything, including the spaces.

Comment: I'm parsing COBOL, so I'm only interested in the keywords. Spaces do not interest me at the moment (it may change).

Comment: @JoeFrambach—I guess it depends on your definition of "token". Spaces aren't [tokens in ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.5) (for example), but might be in some other context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the negated inverse of `\S` and add `.` to the class, like this:

```
/[^\s.]+/g
```

The results give:

```
"      THE QUICK BROWN FOX   JUMPED-OVER THE LAZY(2) DOG.".match(/[^\s.]+/g)
["THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPED-OVER", "THE", "LAZY(2)", "DOG"]
```

This just removes the period from the match.

To add an ending period back to the match:

```
"      THE QUICK BROWN FOX   JUMPED-OVER THE LAZY(2) DOG.".match(/[^\s.]+|\.$/g)
["THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPED-OVER", "THE", "LAZY(2)", "DOG", "."]
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, that is exactly what I was looking for, I really need to sit down and learn regex :-)

Comment: I discovered that I need to support single quoted text as a single token. I found the following regex: `.match(/('[^']+'|[^'\s]+)/g)`, it appears to work, but includes fullstop in the last line if it's not next to a quote.

Comment: I recommend doing this in two passes rather than creating one convoluted regex.

Answer (score 1):

Add a space for `"."` then match it

```
var v = "      THE QUICK BROWN FOX   JUMPED-OVER THE LAZY(2) DOG.".replace(".", " .").match(/\S+/g);

console.log(v);
```

Result:

```
["THE", "QUICK", "BROWN", "FOX", "JUMPED-OVER", "THE", "LAZY(2)", "DOG", "."]
```

Comment: I had thought of this, but I wanted a solution that only used regex. But thank you for the suggestion.